# Is it possible to have cropmarks for every single one of my {minipage} environments?

Tags: minipage, fbox, cropmarks

### Scenario

I'm printing labels, or rather nametags. Eight of those fit on one A4 paper.

### Current approach

My current approach is to create a `{minipage}` environment inside an `\fbox`.
I then set the `\fboxrule` width to `0.5mm`.
this puts every label in a small box, which I can then use as guidelines to cut the labels out of the paper page.

### Problem

However, this is not ideal, because actually cutting exactly on the line is quite difficult, even with a paper cutting guillotine, such that none of those box lines remains on the label.

I'd much rather have crop marks to use as cutting guide lines, which don't end up in the cut-out label, but remains on the off-cuts.

I know there's the `cropmarks` package, which provides crop mars for entire pages, but I need them for my labels which appear several times on one page.

### Question

Is there a package for that, or can I do them manually? And if so, how?

Comment: You could do it using a `picture` environment or TikZ. But I would just use [a label package](https://ctan.org/topic/labels).

Comment: There are also pre-formatted labels.  Alas, Avery doesn't support A4 paper.

Comment: Do these label packages provide for crop marks? I mean technically I just want to add crop marks to an existing layout, not switch the layout to something that might not even have crop marks...